# Why it shows an error getting the content of the badge?

Tags: laravel

I have this code to get the content of a badge stored in column "content" of the badges table. The issue is that it shows "Trying to get property of non-object" in "$pdf->loadHTML($badgeContent->content);"
"

```
$badgeContent = Ticket::with('badge')->find($request->send_to_id)->first();

$pdf = app()->make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML($badgeContent->content);
return $pdf->download('test.pdf');
```

Comment: `if (!empty($badgeContent->content)) {$pdf->loadHTML($badgeContent->content);}`

Comment: Thanks, now appear "Call to a member function build_tree() on null
".